# How to excluded XPATH Nested SPAN Class

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

From the following Html code, I want to select only the first span class Text..

```
<span class="item_amount order_minibasket_amount order_full_minibasket">10 
    <span class="article">Article
        <i class="icon"> >
        </i>
    </span>
</span>
```

This is my current XPATH :

```
//span[contains(@class,'order_minibasket_amount')]
```

when I use this in my Selenium Test, I got the whole SPAN TEXT.. Like :

```
10 Article >
```

I just want to get the "10" article amount..

```
AMOUNT(new PageElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'order_minibasket_amount')]/text()[1]"), "not such Element...."))

  public String getAmount() {
    return amount = PageObjectUtil.findAndInitElementInside(webElement, PageElements.AMOUNT.pe, amount, String.class);
}
```

Many thanks in advance,

Cheers,
koko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `/text()` to the end:

```
//span[contains(@class,'order_minibasket_amount')]/text()
```

Instead of selecting the `span` element node, this XPath will select the set of *text nodes* that are direct children of the `span` element.  This should be a set of two nodes, one containing "10", a newline and four spaces (the text between the opening tag of the target span and the opening tag of the nested span) and the other containing just a newline (between the closing tags of the two spans.  If you only want the *first* text node child (10, nl, spaces) then use

```
//span[contains(@class,'order_minibasket_amount')]/text()[1]
```

Comment: When I use this Xpath "//span[contains(@class,'order_minibasket_amount')]/text()[1]" - I got the element that I want-. But I got this error.. Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//span[contains(@class,'order_sel_minibasket_amount')]/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=36.0.1985.143)

Comment: @KoKo can you edit the question to show the code you're using to execute the XPath?  The expression is correct, and is returning a text node, but it seems that the API you're using requires that you select _element_ nodes only.  You may have to do it in two stages, selecting the element with XPath and then extracting its text node children via some other API.

Comment: This isn't right given the context - Selenium requires your XPath queries to return physical DOM elements that it can work with, hence the error.

Comment: @Arran I was coming at this from the XPath end rather than the Selenium end, I didn't realise that Selemium XPaths had to select only elements as opposed to arbitrary DOM nodes.

Answer (score 1):

What you want cannot be done directly, you will have to resort to [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html) manipulation. Something like:

```
String completeString = driver.findElement(By.className("item_amount")).getText()
String endString = driver.findElement(By.className("article")).getText()
String beginString = completeString.replace(endString, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I am using work around solution...but i am not happy with it. :-(

```
    public String getAmount() {
    String tempAmount = PageObjectUtil.waitFindAndInitElement(PageElements.AMOUNT.pe).getText();
    String output = tempAmount.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z->]", "");
    return amount = output.trim();
}
```

cheers,
KoKo